# SDWebImage Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_cancelCurrentAnimationImagesLoad'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift5, sdwebimage

How to Cancel Current Animation Images load using SDWebImage 5.12.3.

`imageView.sd_cancelCurrentAnimationImagesLoad()`

Comment: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/5.0-Migration-guide

Comment: Hi @Larme, I am following the same don't know how to achieve. can you help me ?
I have to cancel eachtime in prepareforReuse method of UITableViewCell.